# C# XmlDocument Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm trying to access UPS tracking info and, as per their example, I need to build a request like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>
   <AccessLicenseNumber>YOURACCESSLICENSENUMBER</AccessLicenseNumber>
   <UserId>YOURUSERID</UserId>
   <Password>YOURPASSWORD</Password>
</AccessRequest>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<TrackRequest>
   <Request>
     <TransactionReference>
         <CustomerContext>guidlikesubstance</CustomerContext>
     </TransactionReference>
     <RequestAction>Track</RequestAction>
   </Request>
   <TrackingNumber>1Z9999999999999999</TrackingNumber>
</TrackRequest>
```

I'm having a problem creating this with 1 XmlDocument in C#. When I try to add the second:
`<?xml version="1.0" ?> or the <TrackRequest>` 
it throws an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: This
>   document already has a
>   'DocumentElement' node.

I'm guessing this is because a standard XmlDocument would only have 1 root node. Any ideas?

Heres my code so far:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("AccessRequest");
rootNode.SetAttribute("xml:lang", "en-US");
xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

XmlElement licenseNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("AccessLicenseNumber");
XmlElement userIDNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("UserId");
XmlElement passwordNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Password");

XmlText licenseText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("mylicense");
XmlText userIDText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("myusername");
XmlText passwordText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("mypassword");

rootNode.AppendChild(licenseNode);
rootNode.AppendChild(userIDNode);
rootNode.AppendChild(passwordNode);

licenseNode.AppendChild(licenseText);
userIDNode.AppendChild(userIDText);
passwordNode.AppendChild(passwordText);

XmlElement rootNode2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("TrackRequest");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode2);
```

Comment: You might want to post the code where the error occurs.  Otherwise we're like auto mechanics who are asked the question over the phone: "My car won't start.  What's the problem?"

Comment: Also, are you sure that this example they provided is for one request? It looks more like two different types of request.

The first one being to request access, the second being to request the tracking information.

Comment: This is exactly what their example was. We use something similar in classic ASP and both xml requests are sent at the same time via a Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP object.

Comment: Odd, but if the request is coming across as a string, then they can parse the two root nodes into two portions easily enough.  Both @VVS and @MrPeregrination seem to have a handle on how to do it.  Which UPS tracking service is this for?  Didn't know they did this -- I might want to use it.

Comment: Cyberherbalist - its to return the status of a shipment... similar to what you see when you track a UPS packed via their website... it will show you what cities it went through and that status at that location

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An XML document can only ever have one root node. Otherwise it's not well formed. You will need to create 2 xml documents and join them together if you need to send both at once.

Answer (score 2):

Its throwing an exception because you are trying to create invalid xml. XmlDocument will only generate well formed xml.

You could do it using an XMLWriter and setting XmlWriterSettings.ConformanceLevel to Fragment or you could create two XmlDocuments and write them out into the same stream.

Answer (score 0):

Build two separate XML documents and concatenate their string representation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your node structure always be the same. (I don't see any conditional logic.) If the structure is constant you could define an XML template string. Load that string into an XML Document & do a SelectNode to populate individual nodes.

That may be simpler/cleaner than programatically creating the root, elements & nodes.