# Serialize XmlDocument & send via HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, xmldocument

I'm trying to figure out how to properly serialize my XmlDocument and send it via a HTTPWebRequest object.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
Stream requestStream;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track");
request.Method = "POST";

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

XmlSerializerNamespaces xsm = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xsm.Add("", ""); // remove namespace
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(xmlRequest.GetType());
ser.Serialize(requestStream, xmlRequest);

requestStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

A few things I'm uncertain about. I have 2 XmlDocuments I need to send in the same HTTPWebRequest. I've tried before to convert the XmlDocuments to strings and just concatenate them (to send the string) but when I used the StringBuilder / Writer it adds:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <string xmlns="http://myNameSpace/">
```

I already have the declaration in my XmlDocument objects so now its in there twice, and I cannot have the `<string...` part in there. Is it easier to convert the XmlDocuments to strings then concatenate them and send that or is there a easy way to send the XmlDocuments as they are?

**Edit:**

See [C# XmlDocument Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104549/c-xmldocument-nodes)
When I try to convert one of my XmlDocuments to a string it shows up as

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <string xmlns="http://myNamespace/">
      <TrackRequest>
         <Request>
            <TransactionReference>
                <CustomerContext>whatever</CustomerContext>
            </TransactionReference>
         </Request>
         <TrackingNumber>123</TrackingNumber>
      </TrackRequest>
   </string>
```

I want my root to be `<TrackRequest>`

Comment: Can you show what you want the XML to look like? You can't send two documents in a row - there needs to be a root element.

Comment: Also, what is xmlRequest defined as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this question is related to the previous one about 2 xml documents not being able to be combined into one document without wrapping them both in a root node first ([C# XmlDocument Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104549/c-xmldocument-nodes/1104586#1104586)).

If that is the case then you don't want to be serialising the XmlDocuments and sending them to the WebService. Serializing the objects is for transporting/storing the actual object, not the data. You want to just send the webservice the data not the object so just concatenate the two xml documents and send that.

```
use XmlDocument.OuterXml to get the XmlDocument as a string. ie:

XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("Some XML");
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
doc2.LoadXml("Some other XML");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(doc1.OuterXml);
sb.Append(doc2.OuterXml);
```

The just send sb.ToString() to the WebService.

Hope I haven't got completely the wrong end of the stick.

Answer (score 1):

Works (somewhat)! Thanks, heres the code:

```
Stream requestStream;
Stream responseStream;
WebResponse response;
StreamReader sr;
byte[] postData;
string postString;
postString = xmlAccess.OuterXml + xmlRequest.OuterXml;
postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

requestStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
requestStream.Close();

response = request.GetResponse();
responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);

return sr.ReadToEnd();
```

It still doesnt return proper XML though:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <string xmlns="http://namespace/"><?xml version="1.0" ?> <TrackResponse><Response><...
```

Not sure why there's 2x `<?xml version...`

Answer (score -2):

I'm doing this now with UPS, instead of building the documents in XML, I just used string builders like so:

... in code:

```
AddNode("name", "value");
```

...in class:

```
private StringBuilder sb;
public void AddNode(string name, string value) 
{
    sb.Append("<" + name + ">" + value + "</" + name + ">");
}
```

I personally think it's better, because it reduces the server load.