# Loading XmlDocument via HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, xmldocument, user-agent

I need to load an `XmlDocument` from a URL. This has been working but it appears I may need to specify a user agent string.

Since `XmlDocument` doesn't support this directly, I'm trying to do this via `HttpWebRequest`:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "My User Agent";
xml.Load(request.GetRequestStream());
```

However, the call to `xml.Load()` above raises a "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type." exception.

Can someone who understands this better than I help me out?

Comment: this also looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105146/c-serialize-xmldocument-send-via-httpwebrequest

Comment: to me, that seems to be a whole different case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getrequeststream.aspx)() is for request-data.

Check out [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx)( ) instead.

Comment: Yes, `xml.Load(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())` seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the verb you use is incorrect. Does this work?

request.Method = "GET"