# Sending SOAP message with C# Help Needed

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I would like to send a SOAP Message to a Web Service and read the response. My code is as follows: I will appreciate your help.

I hope my question is not repeated, I have looked around for a solution however I have not been successful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace TolunaPush
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string sourceID = "50001255";
        private string email = "adsvine@gmail.com";
        private string firstName = "Muz";
        private string lastName = "Khan";
        private string countryID = "2000077";
        private string countryLanguage = "2000240";
        private string postalCode = "N19 3NU";
        private string dob = "1977-03-08";
        private string gender = "2000247";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sendSoapMessage();
        }

        protected void sendSoapMessage()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.InnerXml = @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                  <soap:Body>
                    <SubmitPanelist xmlns=""http://www.greenfield.com/RegistrationGateway/Messages"">
                      <Registration xmlns=""http://www.greenfield.com/RegistrationGateway/Types"">
                        <Source>
                          <SourceID>" + sourceID + @"</SourceID>
                        </Source>
                        <Email>" + email + @"</Email>
                        <FirstName>" + firstName + @"</FirstName>
                        <LastName>" + lastName + @"</LastName>
                        <CountryUK>
                          <CountryID>" + countryID + @"</CountryID>
                          <Language>" + countryLanguage + @"</Language>
                          <Address>
                            <Postalcode>" + postalCode + @"</Postalcode>
                          </Address>
                        </CountryUK>
                        <DOB>" + dob + @"</DOB>
                        <Gender>" + gender + @"</Gender>
                      </Registration>
                    </SubmitPanelist>
                  </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://coreg.surveycenter.com/RegistrationGateway/PanelistService.asmx");
            //if (proxy != null) req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true);
            // req.Headers.Add("GetClientInfo", "http://tempuri.org/GetClientInfo");

            req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            req.Accept = "text/xml";
            req.Method = "POST";

            Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream();
            doc.Save(stm);
            stm.Close();
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

            stm = resp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stm);
            Response.Write(r.ReadToEnd());
            //Response.Write(stm.ToString());
            //Response.Write(r.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Update
As suggested by Darin. I did as instructed however the following line of code

```
using (var client = new RegistrationBindingsClient("RegistrationBindings"))
```

gives the error

```
The type or namespace name 'RegistrationBindingsClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You haven't specified what the problem is.  Are you getting an error?  What is the error?  Where does it happen?  What are the states of the relevant objects when it happens?  If there's no error, at what point does the behavior of the code deviate from expected behavior?

Comment: Does the web service not have a WSDL if  so you seem to be reinventing the wheel.  The usual way to consume soap web services is to add a web reference or used wsdl.exe.  This will create proxy classes that handle all the soap stuff for you you just call methods  on classes.

Answer (score 9):

The web service you are trying to consume offers a WSDL at the [following address](http://coreg.surveycenter.com/RegistrationGateway/PanelistService.asmx?WSDL). So simply right click on the References in the solution explorer and use the Add Service Reference dialog in Visual Studio and point to the WSDL and it will generate strongly typed classes for you to easily consume the service, just like this:

```
protected void sendSoapMessage()
{
    using (var client = new RegistrationBindingsClient("RegistrationBindings"))
    {
        var registration = new RegistrationType();
        registration.Source = new SourceType();
        registration.Source.SourceID = "50001255";
        registration.Email = "adsvine@gmail.com";
        registration.FirstName = "Muz";
        registration.LastName = "Khan";
        var countryUK = new CountryTypeUK();
        countryUK.CountryID = 2000077;
        countryUK.Language = 2000240;
        countryUK.Address = new AddressTypeUK();
        countryUK.Address.Postalcode = "N19 3NU";
        registration.Item = countryUK;
        registration.DOB = new DateTime(1977, 3, 8);
        registration.Gender = 2000247;

        client.SubmitPanelist(registration);
    }
}
```

See how easy it is. You should not worry about any SOAP and XML plumbing.

And if you are interested in the actual underlying SOAP envelope that is being sent on the wire using this request:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <SubmitPanelist xmlns="http://www.greenfield.com/RegistrationGateway/Messages">
            <Registration xmlns="http://www.greenfield.com/RegistrationGateway/Types">
                <Source>
                    <SourceID>50001255</SourceID>
                </Source>
                <Email>adsvine@gmail.com</Email>
                <FirstName>Muz</FirstName>
                <LastName>Khan</LastName>
                <CountryUK>
                    <CountryID>2000077</CountryID>
                    <Language>2000240</Language>
                    <Income>0</Income>
                    <Education>0</Education>
                    <Address>
                        <Postalcode>N19 3NU</Postalcode>
                    </Address>
                </CountryUK>
                <DOB>1977-03-08</DOB>
                <Gender>2000247</Gender>
            </Registration>
        </SubmitPanelist>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Darin, I added the reference under visual studio web reference for my project. It did not generate any strongly typed class. I had to go to Visual Studio tools to do it from the Visual studio command prompt. A C# file was created called "PanelistService.cs". No config file was created as described by Rajesh in the second answer. I then copied and pasted the file in the project. I am now getting the following error:                                         The type or namespace name 'RegistrationBindingsClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1048006, you should use Add Service Reference dialog, not Add Web Reference. In order for it to be visible your project must be targeting .NET 3.0 or later. If you are using an older version you could still invoke the web service by adding a Web Reference to the WSDL. In both cases strongly typed classes will be generated and automatically added to your project. In the second case they won't probably be named exactly as in my answer. You will have to find their names by exploring the generated metadata.

Comment: Thanks Darin, that works perfectly. Now I am faced with the task of getting the response? Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error message or did you use an HTTP monitor?

Some maybe useful Links:

- [XmlDocument Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335927%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)
- [Similar Question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105146/c-sharp-serialize-xmldocument-send-via-httpwebrequest)  maybe helpful

Comment: Thanks everyone, I shall try your suggestions and report my findindgs here.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the service in 2 methods:

1. By adding a web reference of the service. In visual studio you can right click on your project and select the option Add Web reference and then paste the URL of the service.
2. Generate client proxy from the wsdl using wsdl tool from Visual studio command prompt.The command would be as follows:

c:>wsdl "http://coreg.surveycenter.com/RegistrationGateway/PanelistService.asmx?wsdl

It would generate a .cs file and an output.config. Include the .cs file in your project and you can directly use it to access the service. Make sure that the config file entries are added to your projects config.

If you want to use HttpWebRequest then find the code below :

```
string soap = 
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
   xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
   xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
  <soap:Body>
    <Register xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
      <id>123</id>
      <data1>string</data1>
    </Register>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/WebServices/CustomerWebService.asmx");
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/Register\"");
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
req.Accept = "text/xml";
req.Method = "POST";

using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
{
     using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
     {
          stmw.Write(soap);
     }
}

WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// TODO: Do whatever you need with the response
```

My Service looks like :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class CustomerWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string Register(long id, string data1)
    {
        return "ID.CUSTOMER";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general purpose class you can use to achieve what you need.

**IMPORTANT DISCLAIMER**: You should only use this when you want (or need) to manually issue a SOAP-based web service: in most common scenarios you should definitely use the Web Service WSDL together with the **Add Service Reference** Visual Studio feature, which is the proper way to do that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace Ryadel.Web.SOAP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class to send custom SOAP requests.
    /// </summary>
    public static class SOAPHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a custom sync SOAP request to given URL and receive a request
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The WebService endpoint URL</param>
        /// <param name="action">The WebService action name</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">A dictionary containing the parameters in a key-value fashion</param>
        /// <param name="soapAction">The SOAPAction value, as specified in the Web Service's WSDL (or NULL to use the url parameter)</param>
        /// <param name="useSOAP12">Set this to TRUE to use the SOAP v1.2 protocol, FALSE to use the SOAP v1.1 (default)</param>
        /// <returns>A string containing the raw Web Service response</returns>
        public static string SendSOAPRequest(string url, string action, Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string soapAction = null, bool useSOAP12 = false)
        {
            // Create the SOAP envelope
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
            var xmlStr = (useSOAP12)
                ? @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
                      xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""
                      xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">
                      <soap12:Body>
                        <{0} xmlns=""{1}"">{2}</{0}>
                      </soap12:Body>
                    </soap12:Envelope>"
                : @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                        xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
                        xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                        <soap:Body>
                           <{0} xmlns=""{1}"">{2}</{0}>
                        </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>";
            string parms = string.Join(string.Empty, parameters.Select(kv => String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", kv.Key, kv.Value)).ToArray());
            var s = String.Format(xmlStr, action, new Uri(url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/", parms);
            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(s);

            // Create the web request
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapAction ?? url);
            webRequest.ContentType = (useSOAP12) ? "application/soap+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"" : "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = (useSOAP12) ? "application/soap+xml" : "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            // Insert SOAP envelope
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }

            // Send request and retrieve result
            string result;
            using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

For additional info & details regarding this class you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/soap-web-service-request-asp-net-c-sharp-wsdl-proxy-soapclient/) on my blog.