# Sending SOAP Message with C#

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, soap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending SOAP message with C# Help Needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139837/sending-soap-message-with-c-sharp-help-needed)

I had posted a question at
[Sending SOAP message with C# Help Needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139837/sending-soap-message-with-c-sharp-help-needed)

I followed the solution suggestion by Darin Dimitrov.

However I have the following issues:

I added the reference under visual studio web reference for my project. It did not generate any strongly typed class. I had to go to Visual Studio tools to do it from the Visual studio command prompt. A C# file was created called "PanelistService.cs". No config file was created as described by Rajesh in the second answer. I then copied and pasted the file in the project.

I am now getting the following error: The type or namespace name 'RegistrationBindingsClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also need to be able to get the response. Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Here is some code which was requested

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using service1;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var registration = new RegistrationType();
        registration.Source = new SourceType();
        registration.Source.SourceID = "50001255";
        registration.Email = "adsvine@gmail.com";
        registration.FirstName = "Muz";
        registration.LastName = "Khan";

        var countryUK = new CountryTypeUK();
        countryUK.CountryID = 2000077;
        countryUK.Language = 2000240;
        countryUK.Address = new AddressTypeUK();
        countryUK.Address.Postalcode = "N19 3NU";

        registration.Item = countryUK;
        registration.DOB = new DateTime(1977, 3, 8);
        registration.Gender = 2000247;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which versions of the .NET framework and of Visual Studio are you using??

Comment: Sounds like you have the type in the wrong namespace.  What is your project's main namespace, and what namespace is the type you're importing attempting to use?  Some code would help us understand your problem better.

Comment: (a) if you had followed Darin's advice, it would have created a service reference which dynamically creates the classes for you to use.  These classes would not appear in your solution, but would be available after including the proper namespace in your file. (b) you should have updated your original question/commented on the response rather than asking a new question covering the same basic problem.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: The project namespace is TolunaPush

Comment: Did you include the .cs file in a VS project or just copied it in a folder? If you have included it in the project you might have omitted its namespace - right-click on it and then 'resolve'