# what is the best way to pass a soap message from wcf service to another wcf service

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a wcf service(say WCF1).
This WCF1 calls another WCF service(say WCF2) and this WCF2 expects XML soap message as input parameter.
Now my Question is

how to generate soap from WCF1.
i have data like as follows:

```
 obj.username="abcd";
 obj.password="123abc";
```

this obj is passed as input to WCF2 as an xmlSOAP messg.
how to generate soap from my data(obj).

is this the only [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139837/sending-soap-message-with-c-sharp-help-needed)

Comment: Is the call internal or are you going to a service with a different base address?

Comment: with different base address