# Error Deserializing SOAP xml to object

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I am having trouble deserializing my incoming SOAP xml to genereated class object. I recieve the error

"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --->     System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <Body xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> was not expected. at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read9_ArrayOfNotifications()"

**XML I am trying to deserialize**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
   <OrganizationId>00DJ0000003K7uaMAC</OrganizationId>
   <ActionId>04kJ00000008Q0hIAE</ActionId>
   <SessionId>00DJ0000003K7ua!AR0AQAx0zs6_ygb_th_XWsRIh_RWuW29JcFnlUFOGvutkXmCRlvTzKEgFIOWEfcA93iOFSmnYts7TBY7qil7QzEbGnN4KeY0</SessionId>
   <EnterpriseUrl>https://cs10.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/30.0/00DJ0000003K7ua</EnterpriseUrl>
   <PartnerUrl>https://cs10.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0/00DJ0000003K7ua</PartnerUrl>
   <Notification>
    <Id>04lJ00000097hkbIAA</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:Account" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>001J000001JMlMTIA1</sf:Id>
     <sf:Account_Code__c>AC-00001</sf:Account_Code__c>
     <sf:CreatedDate>2014-04-17T14:14:56.000Z</sf:CreatedDate>
     <sf:Name>test account12</sf:Name>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
  </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Here's the wsdl generated class**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by wsdl, Version=4.0.30319.17929.
// 
namespace GenomindSFDCOutboundMessages.Account {
    using System;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.ComponentModel;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="NotificationBinding", Namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(sObject))]
    public interface INotificationBinding {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("notificationsResponse", Namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")]
        notificationsResponse notifications([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("notifications", Namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")] notifications notifications1);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")]
    public partial class notifications {

        private string organizationIdField;

        private string actionIdField;

        private string sessionIdField;

        private string enterpriseUrlField;

        private string partnerUrlField;

        private AccountNotification[] notificationField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string OrganizationId {
            get {
                return this.organizationIdField;
            }
            set {
                this.organizationIdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string ActionId {
            get {
                return this.actionIdField;
            }
            set {
                this.actionIdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public string SessionId {
            get {
                return this.sessionIdField;
            }
            set {
                this.sessionIdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string EnterpriseUrl {
            get {
                return this.enterpriseUrlField;
            }
            set {
                this.enterpriseUrlField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PartnerUrl {
            get {
                return this.partnerUrlField;
            }
            set {
                this.partnerUrlField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Notification")]
        public AccountNotification[] Notification {
            get {
                return this.notificationField;
            }
            set {
                this.notificationField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")]
    public partial class AccountNotification {

        private string idField;

        private Account sObjectField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Id {
            get {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public Account sObject {
            get {
                return this.sObjectField;
            }
            set {
                this.sObjectField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
    public partial class Account : sObject {

        private string account_Code__cField;

        private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> createdDateField;

        private bool createdDateFieldSpecified;

        private System.Nullable<bool> is_Record_Deleted__cField;

        private bool is_Record_Deleted__cFieldSpecified;

        private string nameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public string Account_Code__c {
            get {
                return this.account_Code__cField;
            }
            set {
                this.account_Code__cField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate {
            get {
                return this.createdDateField;
            }
            set {
                this.createdDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool CreatedDateSpecified {
            get {
                return this.createdDateFieldSpecified;
            }
            set {
                this.createdDateFieldSpecified = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public System.Nullable<bool> Is_Record_Deleted__c {
            get {
                return this.is_Record_Deleted__cField;
            }
            set {
                this.is_Record_Deleted__cField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool Is_Record_Deleted__cSpecified {
            get {
                return this.is_Record_Deleted__cFieldSpecified;
            }
            set {
                this.is_Record_Deleted__cFieldSpecified = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public string Name {
            get {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Account))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(AggregateResult))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
    public partial class sObject {

        private string[] fieldsToNullField;

        private string idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fieldsToNull", IsNullable=true)]
        public string[] fieldsToNull {
            get {
                return this.fieldsToNullField;
            }
            set {
                this.fieldsToNullField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public string Id {
            get {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
    public partial class AggregateResult : sObject {

        private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
            get {
                return this.anyField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")]
    public partial class notificationsResponse {

        private bool ackField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public bool Ack {
            get {
                return this.ackField;
            }
            set {
                this.ackField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my method that is being executed when the message is received. I'm using SOAP UI to send the message for testing

```
[WebMethod]
public void EchoSoapRequest(int input)
{
    // Initialize soap request XML
    XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();          

    // Get raw request body
    using (Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
    {
        // Move to begining of input stream and read
        receiveStream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            // Load into XML document
            xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);
        }
    }

    var notifications = xmlSoapRequest.GetElementsByTagName("soapenv:Body")[0].OuterXml;

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(notifications)))
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OutboundMessages.Account.notifications));
        object obj = (OutboundMessages.Account.notifications)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }            

}
```

I am not sure why I can't deserialize the xml content.

Comment: looks like you have your soap Envelope and body done incorrectly look at this link and you may be able to see this from a template standpoint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139837/sending-soap-message-with-c-sharp-help-needed

Comment: here is an example of [MSDN Soap Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k1y9z356(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I have no idea why you think that would work. When your `WebMethod` is called, the request has already been consumed. There should be nothing in the input stream at all.

Comment: Also, please specify your scenario clearly. I know a little about SalesForce.com, so I can imagine you are being notified of something by SFDC. But what does `EchoSoapRequest` have to do with it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders EchoSoapRequest is just the name of the method to receive the message from SFDC (http://desalasworks.com/article/how-to-obtain-soap-request-body-in-c-web-services/)..when i run the code the notifications variable does have the soap xml message inside..so there is data in the input stream

Comment: Then something is badly wrong. Is SFDC sending two SOAP envelopes?

Comment: @JohnSaunders no..just the one

Comment: Then why does `EchoSoapRequest` take an `int` parameter? What happens if you give it a `notifications` parameter? It should get deserialized for you.

Comment: that int parameter is just there from the example..i even removed it..i dont want to pass in any parameters..i just want to get the raw data that is being sent to the service and then deserialize it because i have differnt types of notifications classes

Comment: It pains me to see code like this, when there are libraries that people have made to make this 10000x easier, try servicestack.net, go to downloads, scroll to bottom for their older free version that is still good.