# Convert string to xml in c# gives whitespace error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm not a .NET dev but have a simple (or should be simple!) task to accomplish.  I basically need to generate a chunk of XML from various string values and format this into a valid XML object in C#.  The code I have is like this:

```
private XDocument BuildPayload(string weight, string fromCountryCode, string fromZipCode, string toCountryCode, string toZipCode, string serviceTypeCode, string packageTypeCode, string pickupTypeCode)
    {

        string upsAccessLiscenseNumber = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string upsUserID = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        string upsPassword = "xxxxxxxxx";
        string unitOfMeasurementWeight = "LBS";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Clear();
        sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
        sb.Append(" <AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>");
        sb.Append("     <AccessLicenseNumber>").Append(upsAccessLiscenseNumber).Append("</AccessLicenseNumber>");
        sb.Append("     <UserId>").Append(upsUserID).Append("</UserId>");
        sb.Append("     <Password>").Append(upsPassword).Append("</Password>");
        sb.Append(" </AccessRequest>");
        sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
        sb.Append(" <RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang='en-US'>");
        sb.Append("     <Request>");
        sb.Append("         <TransactionReference>");
        sb.Append("             <CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext>");
        sb.Append("             <XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>");
        sb.Append("         </TransactionReference>");
        sb.Append("         <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction>");
        sb.Append("         <RequestOption>Shop</RequestOption>");
        sb.Append("     </Request>");
        sb.Append("     <PickupType>");
        sb.Append("         <Code>").Append(pickupTypeCode).Append("</Code>");
        sb.Append("     </PickupType>");
        sb.Append("     <Shipment>");
        sb.Append("         <Shipper>");
        sb.Append("             <Address>");
        sb.Append("                 <PostalCode>").Append(fromZipCode).Append("</PostalCode>");
        sb.Append("          <CountryCode>").Append(fromCountryCode).Append("</CountryCode>");
        sb.Append("             </Address>");
        sb.Append("         </Shipper>");
        sb.Append("         <ShipTo>");
        sb.Append("             <Address>");
        sb.Append("                 <PostalCode>").Append(toZipCode).Append("</PostalCode>");
        sb.Append("                 <CountryCode>").Append(toCountryCode).Append("</CountryCode>");
        sb.Append("             </Address>");
        sb.Append("         </ShipTo>");
        sb.Append("         <Service>");
        sb.Append("             <Code>").Append(serviceTypeCode).Append("</Code>");
        sb.Append("         </Service>");
        sb.Append("         <Package>");
        sb.Append("             <PackagingType>");
        sb.Append("                 <Code>").Append(packageTypeCode).Append("</Code>");
        //sb.Append("                   <Description>Package</Description>");
        sb.Append("             </PackagingType>");
        sb.Append("             <Description>Rate Shopping</Description>");
        sb.Append("             <PackageWeight>");
        sb.Append("                 <UnitOfMeasurement>");
        sb.Append("                 <Code>").Append(unitOfMeasurementWeight).Append("</Code>");
        sb.Append("                 </UnitOfMeasurement>");
        sb.Append("                 <Weight>").Append(weight).Append("</Weight>");
        sb.Append("             </PackageWeight>");
        sb.Append("         </Package>");
        sb.Append("         <ShipmentServiceOptions/>");
        sb.Append("     </Shipment>");
        sb.Append("</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());
        return doc;
    }
```

However, when I call this I get an error:

```
Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.
```

I've found a couple of posts suggesting things (like putting the `sb.Clear()` in there) but nothing works.  It seems to think there's some space at the top of the XML string, but I can't see that there is.  The only slightly dodgy thing I can see is that there are two `<?xml version='1.0'?>` lines in there.  This has come from the UPS docs though, and I have an old Classic ASP app that uses pretty much this exact same XML and it works fine, so I'm not sure that's the problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this please?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep the line-formatting, use `sb.AppendLine` rather that `sb.Append`. (this will not fix your problem, though)

Comment: The answers that say you have two XML documents here, not one, are obviously correct. However your wider problem is that you are generating XML via string manipulation. A more robust way to work might be to have a template XML document stored in a separate file or resource, have your program parse it into an `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`, then just poke the values you need into the relevant places using something like an XPath.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm kind of tied to what the API is expecting, so I have to post the 2 XML files together.  Actually posting them as a string works - there's no need in this instance to convert to an 'proper' XML object actually.  It doesn't quite feel right, but it works.  I found this too which is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104549/c-sharp-xmldocument-nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called it with the two declarations. You can only have one declaration and one root element in the document. You've got two separate documents there.

Anything that successfully reads that must not be checking for a valid XML document - maybe a simple reader that only reads one element at a time instead of an entire document.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the XML that you are generating is definitely **not** a valid XML *document*. It's actually 2 XML documents, one after the other.

As a side note, you might want to use the .Net XmlWriter class for building the XML document as it is more expressive and might help you pinpoint any mistakes you are making in forming the document.

However, of this is supposed to be just **a chunk of XML** than what you really want is to parse it as a **document fragment** and remove the `<?XML ... ?>` declarations altogether.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there the line `<?xml version='1.0'?>` must be the first line in an XML document and there must be exactly **one** root node. You have no root node / or two root nodes: AccessRequest and RatingServiceSelectionRequest. It seems like you are just appending one xml doc to another.

You should put both nodes RatingServiceSelectionRequest and AccessRequest in one root node

Comment: Ah-ha!  That would be it.  This is the format suggested (used) by the UPS shipping API, so I need to find a way to pass this to UPS it it's current (invalid) format.  Since it's being posted as a HTTP request it probably doesn't even need to be converted to XML in my code - it can just be sent as a string.  I'm not sure why I funnelled myself into converting it into a XML object - it just felt right, but then if it doesn't work I can't do that, it probably just needs to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

It's incorrect XML. XML should have only one root and one xml declaration.